# DynamicServerError: Dynamic server usage: headers in NEXTJS 13.3

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, production-environment, next.js13

I'm Facing an issue while deployment of my Ecommerce Nextjs13 App on Vercel. Application works fine in local Environment but while hosting I got an error listed Below

```
Error in getting all categories: DynamicServerError: Dynamic server usage: headers
    at staticGenerationBailout (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/536.js:181:21)
    at Object.headers (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/616.js:201:62)
    at handleReqBailout (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/616.js:3048:35)
    at Object.get (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/616.js:3068:13)
    at AuthCheck (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/api/Admin/category/delete-category/route.js:237:23)
    at GET (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/api/Admin/category/getCategory/route.js:164:67)
    at async /vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/616.js:3352:37 {
  digest: 'DYNAMIC_SERVER_USAGE'
}
```

Here's is What I am doing ,

I have a Dashboard Page , Where I fetch all categories data and then set it in redux store , then In child component i get that data and display it in datatables

Here is my code

**/api/Admin/category/getCategory**

```
import connectDB from "@/DB/connectDB";
import AuthCheck from "@/middleware/AuthCheck";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import Category from "@/model/Category";

export async function GET(req: Request) {
  try {
    await connectDB();
    const isAuthenticated = await AuthCheck(req);

    if (isAuthenticated) {
      const getData = await Category.find({});
      if (getData) {
        return NextResponse.json({success  :true , data : getData});
      } else {
        return NextResponse.json({status: 204 , success: false, message: 'No categories found.' });
      }
    } else {
      return NextResponse.json({status: 401 , success: false, message: "You are not authorized." });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error in getting all categories:', error);
    return NextResponse.json({status : 500 , success: false, message: 'Something went wrong. Please try again!' });
  }
}
```

**Admin Dashboard Page**

```
"use client"
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import AdminNavbar from '@/components/AdminNavbar';
import AdminSidebar from '@/components/AdminSidebar';
import SuperComponent from '@/components/SuperComponent';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import useSWR from 'swr'
import { get_all_categories } from '@/Services/Admin/category';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setCatLoading, setCategoryData } from '@/utils/AdminSlice';


interface userData {
  email: String,
  role: String,
  _id: String,
  name: String
}



export default function Dashboard() {
  const Router = useRouter();
  const dispatch  = useDispatch();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const user: userData | null = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || '{}');
    if (!Cookies.get('token') || user?.role !== 'admin') {
      Router.push('/')
    }
  }, [])



  const { data : categoryData , isLoading : categoryLoading } = useSWR('/gettingAllCategoriesFOrAdmin', get_all_categories)
  if (categoryData?.success  !== true) toast.error(categoryData?.message)

  useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(setCategoryData(categoryData?.data))
    dispatch(setCatLoading(categoryLoading))

  }, [categoryData , dispatch , categoryLoading])
 


  return (
    <div className='w-full h-screen flex  bg-base-200 overflow-hidden'>
      <AdminSidebar />
      <div className='w-full h-full '>
        <AdminNavbar />
        <div className='w-full h-5/6  flex flex-wrap items-start justify-center overflow-y-auto  px-4 py-2'>
         <SuperComponent />
        </div>
      </div>
      <ToastContainer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed this error by adding

export const dynamic =  'force-dynamic' in my Api routes file
[image]

Comment: This solution fix the build error, but the routing is not working.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail what issue you are facing , in my case my routes and app works fine in local development but when i push code to production, some of my routes throw above errors soi searched around and got the fix i mentioned above

Comment: The error was already been resolve, just forgot on how I did it.

Comment: Adding export const revalidate = 0; also fixed the issue for me